# Issues with TelerikReports upgrade to 2023 R3, with Angular front end reports wrapper

Tags: telerik-reporting

I updated my front end ***package.json*** to use the Telerik `Angular` Report Wrapper (published in ***Nov 2023***):

```
"@progress/telerik-angular-report-viewer": "^20.23.1114",
```

i.e. as per npm - "This version .. requires Telerik Report Server .. 17.2.23.1114.

and the ***backend*** to `Telerik.Reporting 17.2.23.1114`:

[image]

---

- Now when I access the stats page in our website

  http://oak-3cvrvv3/Har/en-US/#/statistics
- I get the error:

  ```
  Cannot access the Reporting REST service. (serviceUrl = 'http://oak-3cvrvv3/HarAPI/api/reports'). Make sure the service address is correct and enable CORS if needed. (https://enable-cors.org)
  ```

Now in Postman, this **Post** request on the OLD version just returns a clientId

```
 https://devapp01.topsyn.com/har/api/reports/clients
```

[image]

But when I make the same request in my upgrade local envir, I get errors:

[image]

---------------------------------------------------------------------

- and my ReportsController in .net 4.6

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Http;
using Telerik.Reporting.Cache.Interfaces;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi;
using System.Web;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services;
using Telerik.Reporting;

namespace SynWAPI.Controllers
{
    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    [RoutePrefix("api/reports")]
    public class ReportsController : ReportsControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("IsReady")]
        public IHttpActionResult IsReady()
        {
            return Ok("OK Dude !");
        }

       // new method for latest TelerikReports 2023 release, as per https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/embedding-reports/host-the-report-engine-remotely/rest-service-report-source-resolver/use-custom-report-source-and-document-resolvers?_ga=2.110664256.43783964.1705943251-1117489418.1701363987&_gl=1*3x39f9*_ga*MTExNzQ4OTQxOC4xNzAxMzYzOTg3*_ga_9JSNBCSF54*MTcwNjExMTg5NC4yMC4xLjE3MDYxMTI5MTMuNDYuMC4w*_gcl_au*NTYzNzA2MTUwLjE3MDEzNjM5ODY.
        public ReportSource Resolve(string uri, OperationOrigin operationOrigin, IDictionary<string, object> currentParameterValues)
        {
            {
                var appPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
                string reportPath = Path.Combine(appPath, @".\Reports");

                var reportPackager = new ReportPackager();
                Report report = null;
                using (var sourceStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(reportPath))
                {
                    report = (Report)reportPackager.UnpackageDocument(sourceStream);
                }              
                return new InstanceReportSource
                {
                    ReportDocument = report
                };
            }
        }

        //[Obsolete]
        //protected override IReportSourceResolver CreateReportResolver()   // THIS IS THE PRE-UPGRADE METHOD, WHICH CURRENTLY WORKS IN PRODUCTION 
        //{
        //    var appPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
        //    var reportsPath = Path.Combine(appPath, @".\Reports");

        //    return (IReportSourceResolver)new ReportFileResolver(reportsPath).AddFallbackResolver(new ReportTypeResolver());
        //}

        [Obsolete]
        protected override ICache CreateCache()
        {
            return Telerik.Reporting.Services.Engine.CacheFactory.CreateFileCache();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things we ended up doing, with help from this support ticket:
https://www.telerik.com/forums/upgrading-telerikreports-to-2023-r3-trial-version-with-angular-front-end

Firstly, I installed the **TelerikReports 2023 SP1 Trial** .msi pacakge on my box. See C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress, and the `Telerik Reporting R3 2023` folder has an "examples" section.

Opening our solution, I IGNORED the Telerik Upgrade Wizard.

1. Starting from old version of my .net solution, using NuGet Manager to first upgrade to NewtonSoft v13.0.3.
2. Using NuGet Manager "browse" window, find and install both  `Telerik.Reporting.Trial` v17, as well as the v17 `WebApi`  [image]
   [image]
3. Open up the .Net backend samples in this project dir: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik Reporting R3 2023\Examples\CSharp\.NET Framework\ReportingRestServiceCorsDemo`
4. The "greedy route in the routes configuration" issue: the Telerik routes should go first - see `Global.asax.cs` of their sample project.

```js
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi.ReportsControllerConfiguration.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);


    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

5. Finally, the `ReportController.cs` itself, also in their sample proj. Ours was quite old. Here's the new:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using ....Objects;
using ....Common.Converter;
using ApplicationWAPI.Models;
using Telerik.Reporting.Cache.Interfaces;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services.Engine;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi;
using System.Web;
using Telerik.Reporting.Cache.File;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services;

namespace ApplicationWAPI.Controllers
{
    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    [RoutePrefix("api/reports")]
    public class ReportsController : ReportsControllerBase
    {

        static readonly ReportServiceConfiguration configurationInstance =
        new ReportServiceConfiguration
        {
            HostAppId = "MyApp01",
            ReportSourceResolver = new UriReportSourceResolver(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports"))
                .AddFallbackResolver(new TypeReportSourceResolver()),
            Storage = new FileStorage(),
        };

        public ReportsController()
        {
            this.ReportServiceConfiguration = configurationInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

6. Using Postman (or whatever) run your local proj and try to hit the `ReportsController` - i.e. `http://localhost:49759/api/reports/formats`
   You should get some metadata back from the Telerik DLLs:

`[{"name":"PDF","localizedName":"Acrobat (PDF) file"},{"name":"CSV","localizedName":"CSV (comma delimited)"},{"name":"XLS","localizedName":"Excel 97-2003"},{"name":"RTF","localizedName":"Rich Text Format"},{"name":"IMAGE","localizedName":"TIFF file"},{"name":"MHTML","localizedName":"Web Archive"},{"name":"XPS","localizedName":"XPS Document"}]`

7. For the front-end, if you're using `angular` go here:

https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/embedding-reports/display-reports-in-applications/web-application/angular-report-viewer/angular-report-viewer-overview

ex/

```html
<tr-viewer    
    [containerStyle]="viewerContainerStyle"
    [serviceUrl]="serviceUrl"
    [reportSource]="reportSource"
    [viewMode]="'INTERACTIVE'"
    [scaleMode]="'SPECIFIC'"
    [scale]="1.0"
    [templateUrl]="telerikTemplateUrl"
    [parameters]="{
        editors: {
            multiSelect: 'COMBO_BOX',
            singleSelect: 'COMBO_BOX'
        }
    }"
>
</tr-viewer>
```

8. **Front-end, updated HTML templates**

   See C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik Reporting R3 2023\Html5\ReportViewer\templates

Answer (score 1):

Version 20.23.1114 of the HTML5 (jQuery) Angular viewer should work with 17.2.23.1114 REST service. I prefer to test with
`api/reports/version` or with `api/reports/formats` endpoint to see if the service is up and running. I would try to build the REST service project in my development environment (Vusial Studio 2022 for me) and see if the same error pops out here (I expect the build to fail). You can check the reference to the Newtonsoft package and debug which version is loaded.

Comment: thanks for those suggestions. all good points, but I posted a very detailed answer based on what my colleague and I did. I also posted the Telerik ticket which we used as a guide: https://www.telerik.com/forums/upgrading-telerikreports-to-2023-r3-trial-version-with-angular-front-end